# Packaging and building python namespace packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools, packaging, namespace-package

**What I am trying to do?**
Have one large package with several installable parts, which need to work together, but specific parts can be used on their own. I decided to use namespace package, as it seems to do what I want.

**Problem**
How do I actually build a namespace package?

**My example**
I have a following namespace package, with each of the subpackages containing some modules not listed here. I am using `setuptools`.

```
.
|-mypkg
  |- core
  |    |- setup.py
  |    |- mynmspc
  |         |- util
  |- compute
  |    |- setup.py
  |    |- mynmspc
  |         |- funcs
  |- plotting
       |- setup.py
       |- mynmspc
            |- graphs
- setup.py
```

Now I can build a wheel of this package `python setup.py bdist_wheel`. However if I want to have e.g. `core` subpackage installable by itself do I have to create another wheel for it? What would be the best practice if I would like to give users option to either install the whole package or any of the listed subpackages? Is there a way to automatically build all nested wheels of the main package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use latest python native namespace packages to allow users to install extensions-like packages (`mypkg-core`, `mypkg-compute`,...), you should create different folders for each package like so

```
mypkg-core/
    mypkg/ # no __init__.py here
        core/
            __init__.py
        setup.py

mypkg-compute/
    mypkg/ # no __init__.py here
        compute/
            __init__.py
        setup.py
```

where each `setup.py` is like the following

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_namespace_packages

setup(
    name='mypkg-core',
    ...
    packages=find_namespace_packages(include=['mypkg.*'])
)
```

And you will need to build a whl for each package.

With this configuration, users will be able to

```
pip install mypkg-core
pip install mypkg-compute
```

And access them via the same `mypkg` namespace:

```py
import mypkg.core
import mypkg.compute
```

Don't forget to use `find_namespace_package` from `setuptools` in `setup.py` for each subpkg.

Please always refer to the [official documentation about native namespace packages.](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/#native-namespace-packages).

However, I would suggest an easier way to distribute your package by adding the subpackages dependencies as `extras` grouped with the name of the subpackage. This way the users can use the subpackage only if they install the whole package with

```
pip install mypkg[compute]
```